# Updating rows using "in" operator in "where" clause

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I stumbled upon SQL behavior I don't understand.  I needed to update several rows in a table at once; started with just finding them:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE field1 IN (SELECT ...)
```

This returned a selection of about 60 rows.  Now I was pretty confident I got the subquery right, so I modified *the first part only*:

```
UPDATE some_table SET field2 = some_value WHERE field1 IN (SELECT ...)
```

In other words, this was exactly as the first query after the `WHERE`.  However, it resulted in 0 rows updated, whereas I would expect those 60.  Note that the statement above *would* change `field2`, i.e. I verified that `some_value` was not present in the selected rows.

The subquery was a modestly complicated SQL piece with 2 (different) tables, 1 view, joins and its own `WHERE` clause.  In case this matters, it happened with Oracle Database 10g.

So, the question is, **why `UPDATE` didn't touch the rows returned by `SELECT`**?

Comment: Does the original query still return ~60 rows?

Comment: Yes.  The database was not modified in any way.

Comment: Just a guess - can you add explicit aliases to all tables/views in the subquery as well as the update table and see if that changes your update result?

Comment: No, sorry, I can't.  This is a production database and I cannot just modify its structure like that.

Comment: I think dpbradley is talking about modifying your SQL statement, not the actual view. For each table/view reference in your SQL, provide an alias for it and qualify each column name in your SQL accordingly.

Comment: in either section of your query, do you alias any tables like "select a.description, b.description from some_table A, some_other_table b where ..." .  If so, make sure your aliases aren't overlapping each other.  As another test case, you could remove any aliases, and go strictly by table names.

Comment: Ah, now I understand.  I will do this tomorrow, I don't have access at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally nailed it down.  Turned out that the view used in subquery selection indirectly (through another view) called a stored procedure/function.  The procedure then accessed the table that was being modified in `UPDATE`.  As a result, Oracle threw exception to the tune of "table `some_table` is being modified and function may not see the result" (don't remember the exact text).  But the function used `when other then return null` in the end, so the error was effectively hidden and the subquery didn't return anything at all — and in turn `UPDATE` had no effect.

Moral: never use overbroad exception catchers.  I follow this rule in other languages, but apparently not in PL/SQL :-/

Answer (score 1):

If "some-table" is actually a view, you may have hit an issue where the system is not able to work out how to update the tables that underlie the view.

Comment: No, `some_table` is a real table.  Subquery, however, does contain one view.  Can that be related?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be related. "some_value" isn't related to the subquery, is it? Also, if the subquery results contain nulls, results can get flakey.

Comment: `some_value` is in fact a string literal, so no it's not related.  No nnulls either...

Comment: In fact the view *was* responsible, although very indirectly, by eventually calling a PL/SQL function.  I posted a self-answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem once where I had mistyped a column name, but there was a column with the same name in the other select, so my inner query "worked" by joining against the outer table.
If you just run the inner query by itself (no outer select or update) does it work?

Comment: I'll need to check that later as I currently (until tomorrow) don't have access.  Hardly, but then I don't see other possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Could be Row-Level Security (also known as Virtual private Database) where you've been given permission to read rows of a table, but not to update them.

Any database links involved ?

Comment: I'm certain there is no row-level security because I work with that database (normally programmatically, but this time I had to issue queries by hand).  What do you mean by database links?

Answer (score 0):

Is it that your field1 is not the first column returned from your subquery?  I suspect that your IN would only compare the value to the results' first column.

Comment: No.  I debugged it and posted a self-answer, but cannot accept it just yet.